# How insert into file_get_contents in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, file-get-contents, prestashop-1.5

I want to insert in `Prestashop 1.5` in a `tpl` file, a `file_get_contents` of a site. It is possible to do directly in a `tpl` file, or I insert into a `php` file and return the content?

Answer (score 1):

Smarty it is a template engine and of course better to get content in php and then assign it to template:

```
$smarty->assign('content', file_get_contents('http://google.com/'));
```

in template

```
{$content}
```

but if you really need to do it in template you can:

```
{assign var='content' value='http://google.com/'}
{$content|file_get_contents}
```

or just

```
{'http://google.com/'|file_get_contents}
```

Comment: thank you very much, work :) if I want add a variabile $var->val, how can do it?

Comment: where $var is a php object, you mean?